# Access SQLite Database located in LOCALAPPDATA at design time

Tags: delphi, firedac

I am using FireDac in Delphi 10.3.2 Pro and would like to set the location for a SQLite database to %LOCALAPPDATA% at design time.  How can I do this, or is it only possible to do this through code at runtime?  Here is an image of what have already tried.  I get "[FireDac] [Phys] [SQLite] ERROR: Unable to open database".

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if IDE is good working with special folder names like `%LOCALAPPDATA%`. But if you do check the Delphi options you see that there is `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variable declared. So perhaps using `LOCALAPPDATA` instead of `%LOCALAPPDATA%` will solve your problem.

Comment: @SilverWarior.  I already tried LOCALAPPDATA, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `%LOCALAPPDATA%` is only meaningful at runtime. You need to resolve it to an actual path, and then use that path to specify the database file to open.